# Event on angular didn't work on datepicker

Tags: angular, angularjs, core-ui

I would like to change my endDate same as startDate on date picker when I change startDate but when I create event on startDate button and change Date on startDate it didn't work (I use date picker from CoreUI) here is my example code

[image]

*If I change startDate so endEnd will change to*

```
// startDate 
<div>
     <small>{{lang.FromDate}}</small>
     <c-date-picker [(date)]="startDate" [ranges]="customRanges"
     (ngModelChange)="onDateChange($event)"></c-date-picker>
</div>
```

my function

```
onDateChange(date: any) {
        // Logic to handle the event when a new date is selected
        console.log("Date selected:", date);
    }
```

I try to test print the value but don't have anything in `consloe.log`(but I try another tag not date picker is work).

`endDate` change when we change `startDate`

Comment: Use (dateChange)="onDateChange($event)"

Comment: you can just look in the CoreUI docs [Outputs] 
https://coreui.io/angular/docs/forms/date-picker

Answer (score 0):

if you use as variables "startDate" and "endDate" change the "endDate" variable. Remember, in Angular we change variables and this variables are showed in the .html automatically thanks binding

```html
    <div>
         <small>{{lang.FromDate}}</small>
         <!--see that you use ngModel--->
         <c-date-picker [(ngModel)]="startDate" [ranges]="customRanges"
         (ngModelChange)="onDateChange($event)"></c-date-picker>
    </div>
    <div>
         <small>{{lang.ToDate}}</small>
         <!--see that you use ngModel--->
         <c-date-picker [(ngModel)]="endDate" [ranges]="customRanges"></c-date-picker>
    </div>
```

`````js
    startDate:any=null;  //you declare two variables
    endDate:any=null;

    onDateChange(date:any) //in change you compare the two variables
    {
       if (this.endDate<date)
          this.endDate=date
    }
````
`````

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `ngModelChange`, please try using `dateChange`. It is the default method provided in their official document. I have tried it, it works.